# wordpress setup given forbidden error

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Installing fresh wordpress-4.2.2 setup on server after fill up form of database details then next

Given Error of

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /wp/wp-admin/install.php on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I have also check the permission of folder and .htaccess

Same wordpress setup working on local server.

Is this any suggestion

Thanks.

Comment: What does your .htaccess file look like?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue goes to in parent Wordpress install plugin of 'All in One WP Security' that would be effected.

Thanks.